# complex sums divided by month

Tags: django, sum

models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Operation(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places = 2)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null = True)
  comments = models.TextField(null = True)
```

Now I want to create a view, with 13 columns:

name of category | -11 | -10 | -9 | ... | -1 | 0

eg.

...food.. | $123.00 | $100.14 | ... | $120.13| $54.12
.clothes.| $555.23 | $232.23 | ... | $200.12| $84.44

where $123.00 for example is a sum of values of operations with category food, made 11 months ago, $100.14 - 10 months ago and so on - $54.12 is sum of current month, 555.23 => the same but category clothes...

I googled a lot, but most of examples are simple - without related class (category)

The correct answer after suggestion of Answer 1:

```
def get_month_sum_series(self):
  import qsstats, datetime
  from django.db.models import Sum
  qss = qsstats.QuerySetStats(self.operation_set.all(), date_field='date', aggregate_field='value',aggregate_class=Sum)
  today = datetime.date.today()
  year_ago = today - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
  return qss.time_series( start_date=year_ago, end_date=today, interval='months')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [django-qsstats](https://github.com/mcroydon/django-qsstats). It has a `time_series` feature which will alow you to get whole series of data for all time in one request. In your case I'd create a method in `Category`, something like:

```
def price_series(self):
    return qsstats.time_series(queryset=self.operation_set.all(), start_date=year_ago, end_date=now, interval='months')
```

Of course, you'll need to set up `year_ago` and `now` variables (for example, using `datetime` module functions).

Comment: YES! I shouldn't use operation__value - it is just value ;D